# Should GUI questions really be duplicates of coded solutions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicate-questions

I recently came across [Using boundaries of city to cover world outside of it in solid color?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253557) on GIS SE. Let me preface this by saying I have particular interest in helping out new SE and/or GIS users. I'm not totally sure where the asker's experience level is with QGIS but I'm guessing it's a relatively new field for him. To me, it seems pretty inhospitable to shove this guys question aside and direct him to a confusing pyQGIS answer that likely wont meet his needs as a new GIS user.

[Inverting Polygons using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187215) is a more similar question that I would accept as being a duplicate to the first linked post. It was also marked as a duplicate to the pyQGIS question. (But in my opinion they are completely different q&a's because the accepted answers are very distinct approaches).

Basically I think the two posts I've linked to should be duplicates of each other but should not be duplicates of the coding post.

Is it fair to keep GUI questions/solutions separate from coding ones? I feel they both have distinct value in this community.

Comment: You are correct, my apologies - I obviously didn't read through the two Q&As properly when I marked that one as a duplicate as I agree with you and with PolyGeo's answer below.  I have reopened that question.

Comment: I think that I have now redirected the duplicates as you suggested.  If not, just comment here or start a new Q&A if I got it way astray.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to treat questions about code separate from questions about the GUI of a GIS product too.

That is why I rarely support questions being coded as:

- [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) and [pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pyqgis); or
- [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) and [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy)
- [arcgis-desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-desktop) and [arcobjects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcobjects)
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcpy)
- [arcgis-pro](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro) and [arcgis-pro-sdk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-pro-sdk)

Sometimes the only answer to a question from a GUI only user is to use code. In that case I think it is OK to say that and make a GUI question a duplicate of a coding one.

However, here I think you have identified a GUI question for which there is a GUI duplicate available so I think it is that GUI duplicate which should be used.

Once the discussion in this Q&A is complete I think we should redirect those duplicates.